# My phone emulator is not working for android studios, what is the easiest way to fix this?

Tags: android

I have recently downloaded the Android Studios software and have tried running a few things in AV mode. It is giving me an error message saying that the Intel HAXM is not installed. Just wondering how to easily get this done smoothly, cheers.

Comment: If you are on Windows, consider this manual https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows